# Windows 7 [System.Drawing.Text.FontCollection] problems in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-7

This code works fine in Windows 10 for TTF, TTC and OTF fonts.

```
$fontCollection = New-Object System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection
if (Test-Path $fontFilePath) {
    $fontCollection.AddFontFile($fontFilePath)
    $fontFamilies = $fontCollection.Families | Foreach-Object {$_.Name}
    Write-Host $fontFamilies
    foreach ($font in $fontCollection.Families) {
        Write-Host "$($font.Name)"
    }
}
```

However, in Windows 7 with an OTF font it fails with `Exception calling "AddFontFile" with "1" argument(s): "File not found."`
But the file IS there, since it has to pass the conditional first.
Is this something that is just broken in older versions of PowertShell/.NET? I have checked [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) and `[System.Drawing.Text.FontCollection]` is a valid type back to
.NET 1.1.

EDIT: Tested on a VM with Windows 7 and PowerShell 5.1, and same problem. So, wither the bug is in .NET and fixed in a build I don't currently have, or it's something else. MAN am I looking forward to being able to stop supporting Windows 7. :|

Comment: The documentation for the .NET Framework implementation also says that a `FileNotFoundException` will be thrown when "The specified font is not supported or the font file cannot be found." - Windows 7 has _limited_ support for OpenType fonts

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Interesting. I double checked that the font file in question really is valid by installing it manually. But I guess "limited support" could mean "You can install manually, and jack little else.". I guess I need to refactor to use the old Windows 7 valid install process for Windows 7, and ONLY use the new approach in Windows 10.

Comment: Yeah, something like that, or at least "re-implementing the required checks for a full superset of OTF features in .NET was too much work"

Comment: Weird thing is OTF is a Microsoft tech. I would EXPECT them to half support someone else's format. But when they can't even support their own stuff, I remember why I do this Windows development in a VM on a Mac. :)

Comment: Also I believe the powershell path and .net path aren’t necessarily the same. Are you specifying the full path?

Comment: @doug-maurer Yes, full path, no wildcards. Only thing that might be an issue is it's a UNC path.